# What material could be used to study magnetic phase transitions in a college laboratory exercise?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, phase-transition, material-science

I am working to develop a simple laboratory exercise in solid state physics to be conducted by fourth year students of physics. The idea of the exercise is for the student to get some experience in magnetic phase transitions.

The setup is rather simple, consisting of a sample placed inside a coil. The sample is connected to a rod that is placed in a container of liquid nitrogen and the temp. is controlled by a simple coil heater. The students would measure the inductance change in the coil with the change of temperature.

My original idea was to use a sample of KMnF3 which has three phase transitions up to 82K. But I am worried that these phase transitions are not as well defined in literature as I would like (some sources specify a fourth phase transition), for a student to work with and comprehend.

My questions is, what would be a interesting, yet simple to understand, material for a student to study? I would prefer at least two phase transitions up to the temperature of liquid nitrogen.

Comment: How about superconductors like Y-Ba-Cu Oxide and Tl-Ba-Cu-oxide but i am afraid that they possibly wont show 3 or 4 transitions.